# Média de latitude e longitude por CEP

Tags: javascript, python, api, google-maps, geolocalização

Estou precisando encontrar o **ponto inicial e o final da latitude/longitude do CEP**. Estou precisando analisar em média uma latitude e longitude e esse parâmetro inicial e final mostraria se essa coordenada faz parte do CEP ou não. Ultimamente estou tendo problemas com API's de geolocalização e estou planejando montar um banco de dados MySQL com todos os CEP's das ruas da minha cidade e médias de latitudes/longitudes para comparar com a latitude e longitude que buscarei no banco.

**Tenho que conseguir essas médias para evitar mais de 1 milhão de consultas via API por dia!**

Por isso pretendo criar esse campo de média que poderia ser a soma da latitude e longitude ou o produto para já verificar rapidamente em que faixa de CEP se encontra aquela coordenada. Eu sei que em diferentes localidades essa média bruta poderá ter repetições mas como meu foco é em apenas uma cidade acredito que não ocorrerá.

**Existe alguma forma de conseguir a coordenada inicial e final de um CEP?**

Exemplo:

```
latitude  = -15.8008398
longitude = -47.86135561

produto = latitude * longitude = (756.2496126044413)

banco = {
     coord_inicial: 750.390348041, (??? Número que preciso encontrar)
     coord_final  : 760.230192319, (??? Número que preciso encontrar)
     cep          : 70100000,
     logradouro   : 'Praça dos três poderes',
     cidade       : 'Brasília'
}
```

Se o produto se encontra entre a *coord_inicial* e a *coord_final* essa localização pertence ao CEP.

Comment: Cara, esse seu problema parece ser muito mais sério do que parece para resolver com média de coordenadas. Digo isso porque: 1) Dificilmente uma rua é reta, então a média não seria exatamente útil. 2) Um mapa trabalha num plano cartesiano, então seria mais útil guardar uma fórmula para uma reta, depois calcular a distância de um ponto nessa reta e ver se esta distância está dentro de um limite aceitável. Mas mesmo assim acho que não resolveria o seu problema.

Comment: 3) Nem sempre um CEP se refere a uma única rua, existem cidades que só têm um CEP apenas. Claro, não é o caso da sua cidade, mas ainda pode ser o caso de que um CEP represente mais de uma rua.
Dito isso vou acompanhar a soluções propostas, pois seu problema é interessante. +1

Comment: @fernandosavio Realmente estou procurando alguma forma de guardar dados repetidos no banco para evitar tantas requisições em API's de geolocalização. É uma ideia inicial a minha de média, já sabia que seria muito mais complexo para ser resolvida com uma simples média, mas como você disse, será que eu conseguiria uma espécie de limite calculando a distância entre esses pontos no plano cartesiano? Obrigado pela dica, vou estudar agora essa alternativa.

Comment: Estava pensando agora... talvez uma alternativa seja fazer o contrário, registrar zonas de lat e long com seu raio ou quadrante e cadastrar os ceps que estão dentro dessa área

Comment: @LeandroAngelo É exatamente isso que estava pensando no final de semana, já baixei os dados do Brasil em formato osm.pbf para estar gerando o meu próprio mapa em ambiente fechado, vou ver se é possível por meio dessa API: [openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org)

Answer (score 2):

O Open Street Map tem uma funcionalidade que pode ser similar ao que você busca, mas a partir do endereço, que pode ser descoberto usando uma API ou um banco de dados de CEP, ambos disponíveis, por exemplo, em: http://cep.la/.

Não tenho conhecimento de javascript, mas no R, pode ser acessado com a função `geocode_OSM()` do pacote `tmaptools`.

Um dos elementos retornados é o bbox, isto é *bounding box matrix*, que pode ser útil.